# WPF Treeview visible Items when Scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I'm using a Multiselect Treeview in MVVM WPF App. A ReactiveCollection is binded as the treeview source. Implemented paging mechanism internally for the source and populated the collection with dummy items.

Now I need to how many items (rows) in the treeview are actually visible in the GUI at any point of time and when the user scrolls. Basically, I want to know the first and last item index in the visible view at any given time and I will implement paging based on this item(row) index and scrolling.

And this logic to detect item index must be implemented as a behaviour for itemscontrol, so that I can reuse it for any itemscontrol.

Comment: I think you will be easier to load the visible elements of trust WPF. And mark Binding property causing slow loading IsAsync = True

Comment: How about only loading 100 items? First time you load 100 and when needed more you load next 100. If visible area is only 30 items and user starts scrolling you would NOT need to load 3 times 30. There are already 100 available anyways. It would reduce the time of loading of items. Loading takes alot of time.

Comment: @devhedgehog Ya. I'm already doing that. I can also find the scrollviewer associated with the treeview. But, now my problem is that I don't know how these displayed items are associated with the scrollviewer. Any way to know the relation between items and scrollviewer ? How the scroll works and the items are scrolled ?

Comment: Extent should be the items.Count and Viewport should be the visible area.